# my jQuery code for setting value in combobox , is not working

Tags: jquery

I have tried to set value for combobox as '-' under some condition. its not working

My code is here :- `jQuery("#cmbSelPrdHourL").combobox('setValue','-');`

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional field in your combobox with value "-",

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="quux">Quux</option>
</select>
```

Now you can set "-" to a combobox using the below script,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mySelect").val("-");
});
```

I have written it in ready()  function just for demo you can write the below line wherever you want,

```
$("#mySelect").val("-");
```

[**Here is a working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/entxud0h/)

**EDIT:** Eventhough your data is coming from a table as you said I don't think it changes anything as you can keep a default `option` within your combobox with value "-"

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="-">-</option>
</select>
```

Just make sure that when you are inserting other options within the combobox from your table, the default option with "-" is not overwritten.

Comment: thank for ur consideration .... select box data is retrieved from table. in case ?

Comment: @HarishS Do you mean you are getting the data from a table and setting it into combobox?

Comment: the code was misplaced. It was working when the value is set after combobox load statement line

Comment: @HarishS I don't think even if the data is coming from a table it makes any difference, check my updated answer